# Cryptkeeper doesn't always work

Tags: software-recommendation, encryption, desktop-apps

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu. I created an encrypted folder. What I notice is that sometimes I'm in the encrypted folder when I unmount it. The files still show. That is, until I unlock and re-lock it. Major security flaw if you ask me.

Am I doing something wrong? I realize that cryptkeeper itself told me there are some vulnerabilities. In the 21st century, I would expect software like this to be updated monthly, if not more often. Not that I don't understand it's free and there may not be enough resources, but still.

Can anyone suggest a fix, if there is one, or tell me if there's a better way to lock a folder than from within the applet, selecting "Unmount" next to the encrypted foler names? Or perhaps another free encryption tool, if you know of better ones for Ubuntu?

**Update:** I just mounted it and my files in that folder are gone. Seriously? How is Cryptkeeper so buggy? Can anyone please suggest something more stable?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it Cryptkeeper is no longer being developed, and there are some really bad vulnerabilities. https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/01/31/cryptkeeper_cooked/

I compress files and password protect them that way.